# query not returning value until after evaluating code or return is already past

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-mvvm

I am implementing Android Component Architecture using the MVVM pattern mentioned in the Google CodeLabs.

I have a Dictionary app that has several entities like word and definition.  I have an activity to display the words (MainActivity) and then from there an Activity where I can add/edit words and definitions (AddEditEntryActivity).

When I go to add a new word, i want to validate that the word has not already been added previously.  I have an isDuplicate(String word) method that goes out to the database to see if the word is in the word table.  I am currently trying to use a LiveData> observable viewmodel object to retrieve the data.  (Mainly, because I cannot figure out how to retrieve a value from the database without LiveData<>.  I tried to just return a List<>, but cannot get the AsyncTask to return value when I need to use it.) The observable seems to run multiple passes. The first pass returns null, and I think this is the one being compared in the isDuplicate(), but then it seems to run a second pass, where the value is found, but obviously is not evaluate.  From there the program tries to add the word and produces an error because the word field is indexed with unique set to true.

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table",
indices = @Index(value = "word", unique = true))
public class Word {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String word;

    @Ignore
    public Word(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public Word(long id, String word) {
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * from word_table WHERE word =:value")
public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordByValue(String value);
```

Repository:

```
public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordByValue(String value) {
    return mWordDao.getWordByValue(value);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public LiveData<List<Word>> getWordByValue(String value) {
    return mWordRepository.getWordByValue(value);
}
```

AddEditEntryActivity:

```
private boolean isDuplicateWord(String word) {
    long index = 0;

    wordViewModel.getWordByValue(word).observe(AddEditEntryActivity.this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Word> words) {
            myWord = words;
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

I have read many articles using LiveData<> and articles using List<>, but cannot find one that will return the value I am looking for as timely as the getAll() method which uses LiveData.  I also tried using an AsyncTask inner class, but again the value was returned after the method calling it returned a null value.  Some even mention using the .get() method of the Asynctask, but also say it is not a good idea because of the asynchronous/synchronous issue.

Can someone help me figure out a way to setup the Dao and then use the method in the UI to retrieve the value when needed on the fly when it needs to be evaluated and not afterwards?

Comment: Well, figured it out.  I need to include the code for the duplicate checking inside of the onChange() method of the viewmodel observable.  However, I am still looking for an answer as to why I could not get an AsyncTask class to work without using LiveData<>, just a List<Word>.  Anyone have thoughts on how to accomplish this so that I do not ALWAYS have to use LiveData<>?  Or is using LiveData<> for a @Query the new norm...?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, thank you for your post.  That makes perfect sense.  I added the unique as an after thought when I realized that I probably needed to make the 'word' field unique.  Would that have any adverse bearing on other tables that need to have a 1:M relationship with the word table? Or do i just need to switch everything to look at the word field and not an id field?  I have hardly ever used anything other than id for primary keys...

Comment: also, i've never seen a Dao return an AsyncTask , so i'm not sure if it's possible. it IS however possible to return an Rxjava observable from it : https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-rxjava-in-android-e52ed7ef32e2 here's a starting point if you're interested

Comment: I will look at that link.  Thanks, @a_local_nobody.  I hope you have a wonderful day!